# Calculate and show sale of only one month(current month) from daily_Sale table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to create a desktop app of my retail shop.

In this application, I want to calculate daily sale of only one month which is running and calculate sale of total month, year etc

Screenshot of Daily Sale table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWQXN.png)

I'm sure this calculate daily sale and show from one day to last day of entry. But I want to show sale only current month and show next month's sale when start.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Daily_Sale ", con);

adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;

dt = new DataTable();
adapt.Fill(dt);

bsource = new BindingSource();
bsource.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;

chart1.Series["Sale"].XValueMember = "Total_Sale";
chart1.Series["Sale"].YValueMembers = "Total_Sale";
chart1.Series["Profit"].XValueMember = "Total_Profit";
chart1.Series["Profit"].YValueMembers = "Total_sale";
chart1.Series["Margin"].XValueMember = "Margin";
chart1.Series["Margin"].YValueMembers = "Total_sale";

chart1.DataSource = hJSportsDataSet8.Daily_Sale;
chart1.DataBind();

cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Daily_Sale ";

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    chart1.Series["Sale"].XValueMember = "Date_Time";
    chart1.Series["Sale"].YValueMembers = "Total_Sale";
    chart1.Series["Profit"].XValueMember = "Date_Time";
    chart1.Series["Profit"].YValueMembers = "Total_Profit";
    chart1.Series["Margin"].XValueMember = "Date_Time";
    chart1.Series["Margin"].YValueMembers = "Margin";
}

void DailySaleFormcs_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'hJSportsDataSet8.Daily_Sale' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.daily_SaleTableAdapter.Fill(this.hJSportsDataSet8.Daily_Sale);

    try
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("today:"+tody);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Total_Sale FROM Daily_Sale ORDER BY Date_Time", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        double tdy_sele = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        //MessageBox.Show("todays sale" + tdy_sele);
        label_tody.Text = tdy_sele.ToString();

        cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Total_Sale) FROM Daily_Sale", con);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        double sum = (double)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
        // MessageBox.Show("sum :" + sum);
        label_totlsale.Text = sum.ToString();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Total_Profit) FROM Daily_Sale", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int proft = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        label_proft.Text = proft.ToString();
```

I think to try the following approach

```
DateTime dat = DateTime.Today;
MessageBox.Show("today"+dat);
DateTime dayone = new DateTime(dat.AddMonths(1).Year, dat.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);
MessageBox.Show("first day of next month:"+dayone);
```

but how by use while, for loop or if condition or other?

Please help me

Comment: you already have the data in your table and just want to show data of the current month , right ?

Comment: yes . but i want more, for further show monthly sale and yearly, may be in  another form or  by extending this form

Comment: checkout my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your datatable in your database looks exactly but use the following query(and code) to fetch the data of the given month(in your case,current month) only :

```
  int month = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString());
  int year = 2018;

  cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Daily_Sale WHERE MONTH(the column name that has dates) = " + month + " AND YEAR(the column name that has dates) =" + year + "", con);
```

**UPDATE**

After having a little discussion in the comments,i understood the OP's situation clearly and i think this is what you are looking for :

```
  ////A class to handle the data of the database

  public class mydata()
  {
    public string name;
    public string dates;
    ///create required variables of required type for each column :)
  }
```

Now we can use a `IDataReader` which will help us get the the required data only and a `List<mydata>` which will hold the filtered data :

```
  List<mydata> filteredData = new List<mydata>();
  ///As OP commented,the date/time look like :  Saturday, April 14, 2018
  string m0nth = "August" 
  //Or      
  string month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString()
  cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Daily_Sale ", con);
  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
  While (dr.Reader())
   {
    string mnth = dr[2].ToString().Split(', ',', ')[0];  ///change 2 with the column count of the date column
    string finalMonth = mnth.Split(" ")[0];

    if (finalMonth == month)
    {
     mydata dt = new mydata();
     dt.name = dr[0].ToString();
     //keep continuing for each column/each variable in the class we created

    filteredData.Add(dt);
  }}}
```

Finally,we display the list in the datagridview :

```
   foreach(mydata dt in filteredData)
    {
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
    row.Cells[0].Value = dt.name;
    ///Keep continuing for each column
    yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
     }
```

Comment: there is only one column for date which Date_Time

Comment: use that name in both cases :) If the answer solved your issue, make sure to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: give me an example of how your date time looks in your database

Comment: I take date from datetimepicker and save in Date_Time column of Daily_Sale table .so it save as varchar or date format and retrieve as string so why we use int and month and year form

Comment: The value should be given as integer...and your screenshot doesn't show the entire date.....The given query will work if your dateTime looks like `1:2:2018 9:00` , that's why i am asking for a date example from your database so that i can modify the code/query

Comment: hmm..so it is not exactly in a date time format ... Are you sure your datatype of the column is dateTime ?

Comment: well , i'll edit my answer , however it will not be as efficient as it would've been if it was `DateTime`

Comment: @hamidjalil , are you still there ?

Comment: check my answer again :)